# Chrome's webkitSpeechRecognition API doesn't give results when running from dockerized environment

Tags: docker, google-chrome, playwright, webkitspeechrecognition

I want to use Google Chrome's built in webkitSpeechRecognition API from a Node.js application by managing a headless Playwright browser. This set-up works fine if I am running the app from my machine:

- Playwight browser gets opened, and i can access the `window.webkitSpeechRecognition` object
- SpeechRecognition succesfully get's initialized: `recognition = new SpeechRecognition()`
- then I can call `recognition.start()` method
- and  I can listen to the `recognition.onresult` events capturing the speech as excepted.

However if I am running the same app from a dockerized environment, everything works as expected (webkitSpeechRecognition gets succesfully initialized and started), but the `recognition.onresult` goes totally silent.

I am also listening for the `recognition.onerror` events, but not getting any useful information about why am I not getting any results back.

Does someone have any information which could be useful for resolving this issue? Maybe there is some kind of security rule which prohibits this API to function in such an environment?